# How can it be verified that the Louis Vuitton website was designed with Vue by inspecting the html source?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frameworks

What are some clues in the source that hint at or prove that it's designed in Vue? Shouldn't it have a line like this?

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
```

That wasn't in the html. Can similar clues be found in other websites to show that they're designed in other JavaScript frameworks like React or Angular?

Comment: How did *you* know it was created using Vue?

Comment: You can use Vue Devtools to check if the website is powered by Vuejs

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary This twitter post by the creator of Vue. https://twitter.com/youyuxi/status/1192201572371042311?lang=en Also saw it mentioned somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use the Chrome extension: [Library Detector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/library-detector/cgaocdmhkmfnkdkbnckgmpopcbpaaejo?hl=en)

Comment: It found these libraries but not Vue. Bootstrap 4.1.2
jQuery 1.9.1
jQuery (Fast path)
boomerang.js 1.737.0
core-js core-js-pure@3.0.0; core-js-pure@3.8.3

But on other sites it can detect Vue.